# Calculate average age of items in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wanting to find the average age of Ticket.opened. Opened is a scope on my ticket model.
This returns a nice result for one ticket.

```
time_ago_in_words(Ticket.last.created_at.to_time)
```

What I am wanting is to do something like this

```
age = []    
Ticket.opened.each do |t|
    age = time_ago_in_words(t.created_at.to_time)+[]
end
average_age = age/Ticket.opened.count
```

I am aware that this code is awful, but it is my best attempt at explaining what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use PostgreSQL then you could fetch average `created_at` time in a single SQL query:

```
avg_created_at = Ticket.opened.average('extract(epoch from tickets.created_at)')
time_ago_in_words(Time.at(avg_created_at))
```

[EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function returns `created_at` value as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. This can be used in an aggregate function, such as [average](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average)

I'm sure MySQL allows such queries too.

Comment: Nice, really elegant! I think its `avg_created_at = Ticket.opened.average('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tickets.created_at)')` on MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp
`

Comment: Nice answer! Gotta say hats off when there's a better solution. +1

Comment: I like this method! Here is the code that I used in the controller:
avg_created_at = Ticket.opened.average('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tickets.created_at)')
And the code from the view: 
<%= time_ago_in_words(Time.at(avg_created_at)) %>
I am getting this error: can't convert FalseClass into an exact number

Comment: @timothywright In your app you use MySQL, correct? Could you open rails console and check the result of `avg_created_at = Ticket.opened.average('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tickets.created_at)')` ?

Comment: yes-I use mysql.
avg_created_at = Ticket.opened.average('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tickets.created_at)')
   (3.7ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.8ms)  SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tickets.created_at)) FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`status` = 0
=> 0.15388397325686e10

Comment: So far so good. `time_ago_in_words(Time.at(0.15388397325686e10))` for me returns `19 days`.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you use local variable `avg_created_at` instead of instance variable `@avg_created_at`, which is required for passing data from the controller to the view.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that :)
This solution is working beautifully, and it is runs pretty fast too. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get this by converting the times to integers and calculating the average. Roughly speaking:

```
times = [2.days.ago, 3.days.ago, 4.days.ago]
average_ticket_time = Time.at(times.map(&:to_i).sum / times.count) # convert to ints and get average
time_ago = Time.now - average_ticket_time # time ago from now
readable_time_ago = (time_ago / 60 / 60).round # divide by 60 secs then 60 mins; round to get closest hour
# => 72 (hours ago)
```

Or in one line:

```
((Time.now - (Time.at(times.map(&:to_i).sum / times.count))) / 60 / 60).round
```

So, on average, 72 hours ago.

You can also divide by an additional `24` to get the time in days: 3 days in this case, which is what you'd expect in this simple example.

In your example, your `times` array would be the following:

```
times = Ticket.opened.map { |ticket| ticket.created_at.to_i }
# or perhaps the following, check the performace:
times = Ticket.opened.pluck(:created_at).map(&:to_i)
```

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on.